# Django Rest Framwork get user in serializer

Tags: python, django, api, serialization, django-rest-framework

I can get the user in my serializer?

For example I have this serializer:

*serializers.py*

```
class ClientSearchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    client = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many=False,
        queryset=Client.objects.filter(user=????),
        slug_field='id'
    )
```

I can filter my queryset from  SlugRelatedField?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CurrentUserDefault` should work for you.

Documentation: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault

Please note:

> In order to use this, the 'request' must have been provided as part of
>   the context dictionary when instantiating the serializer.

If you're using `ModelViewSet` or any view/viewset that takes a `serializer_class` and automatically initializes it for you, then you don't have to worry about that.

Code example:

```
from rest_framework.fields import CurrentUserDefault

class ClientSearchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    client = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many=False,
        queryset=Client.objects.filter(user=CurrentUserDefault()),
        slug_field='id'
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

`CurrentUserDefault()` is a great way to get the user, as has been answered. Another option would be to return a function which returns a serializer class in your view's `get_serializer_class` method. That way you could supply `self.request.user` as an argument to the function.

rest_views.py:

```
class DetailView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return get_client_search_serializer(user=self.request.user)

    ...
```

serializers.py:

```
def get_client_search_serializer(user):
    class ClientSearchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

        client = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
            many=False,
            queryset=Client.objects.filter(user=user),
            slug_field='id'
        )

    return ClientSearchSerializer
```