# Django Rest Framework: foreign key field is required in viewset or serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-rest-viewsets

I am very new to `Django Rest Framework (DRF)`. I have read that `viewsets` are very good, because it reduces the amount of code, but I found it more complex.

**Description:**
Imagine that I want to implement a phonebook API, in which we have some users and each of them has it own contacts and each contact can have several phone number. So, I have three models here.

1. User (Default Django model)
2. Contact

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='contacts'
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=70
    )
    description = models.TextField()
```

3. Phone Number

```
class Phones(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(
        Contact,
        related_name="phones",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    phone_no = models.CharField(
        max_length=11,
    )
```

**Problem Definition**
What I want is to create new contact with the current `request.user`. So I should have my `contact.serializers` like the following:

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all(), slug_field='user')


    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ['id', 'owner', 'name', 'description']
        read_only_fields = ['owner']
```

and my views is like:

```
class ContactViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Contact.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContactSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsCreator]

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.request.method == "GET":
            self.permission_classes = [IsCreator, permissions.IsAdminUser,]

        if self.request.method == "POST":
            self.permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated,]

        if self.request.method == "PUT":
            self.permission_classes = [IsCreator]

        if self.request.method == "DELETE":
            self.permission_classes = []

        return super(ContactViewSet, self).get_permissions()
```

**Error** Whenever I want to post a new contact using `postman`, I have pass the `name`, `description` and `owner` and it should automatically detects the owner from the request but it doesn't and I have got the following error:

[image: postman screenshot]

**PS:** If it is necessary to checkout the project here is [my project link](https://github.com/mostafaghadimi/django_test).

What should I do?

Comment: `it should automatically detects the owner from the request` I did not see any code doing this though?

Comment: could be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37613293/django-rest-framwork-get-user-in-serializer

Comment: @Alvi15 Would you please give me an answer? I really need your help.

Comment: look at the related link and see if it works.

Comment: @Alvi15 I got a new error

Comment: Then fix the error yourself... Or you know, elaborate more if you need help

Comment: @Alvi15 I really need help man. I don't know what should I do. If it was clear for me I wouldn't ask it here.

Comment: I already give you a link that could help, it doesn't work (okay maybe it's a different problem) but then you didn't elaborate more on what error you got. How I'm supposed to help if all I can work with is "i got a new error" ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225141/discussion-between-mostafa-ghadimi-and-alvi15).

Comment: @Alvi15 I will edit my post in 1 minute.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is add currentuserdefault. like this

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ['id', 'owner', 'name', 'description']
```

And in your view code remember to pass request in context. Like this

```
class ContactViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Contact.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContactSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsCreator]

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = super().get_serializer_context()
        context.update({"request": self.request})
        return context
```

Comment: `TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got HiddenField(default=CurrentUserDefault()).` this error is just occured.

Comment: I've installed your app and did the above changes ive suggested and its working fine. But one thing please make sure in contactviewsets remove this `def perform_create(self, serializer):
         return serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved after applying the below changes.

**apps.contacts.views.py**:

add the following method to the body of the class

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    return serializer.save(owner = self.request.user)
```

**apps.contacts.serializers.py**:

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'description', 'owner']
```

**PS** I am also looking for more answers, in this case add your answer.