# Configure Django Rest Framework to populate user field with logged in user before serializer validation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an API endpoint that supports the POST method which works if I include the `user` in the request payload.

I would like to eliminate this from the request payload and have DRF just use the logged in user.

I am getting the following error when I omit the `user` from the request body:

```
HTTP 400 Bad Request
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "user": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

This appears to be coming from when the framework calls `serializer.is_valid()`.

How do I configure DRF to populate the user from `request.user` so that serializer validation doesn't fail?

**models.py**

```
class Task(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    domain = models.CharField(max_length=settings.MAX_CHAR_COUNT)
```

**serializers**

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=CustomUser.objects.all(), slug_field='email')

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ['id', 'created', 'domain', 'user']
```

**views.py**

```
class TaskApiViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated,]
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
    task_service = TaskService()

    """
        GET /api/tasks
    """
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user

        if user.is_superuser:
            return Task.objects.all()

        return Task.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

    """
        POST /api/tasks
    """
    def create(self, request):
        domain = request.data['domain']

        can_create_task = self.task_service.can_create_task(user=request.user, domain_name=domain)

        if not can_create_task:
            raise PermissionDenied(code=None, detail=None)

        return super().create(request)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to completely override your `ViewSet`'s `create()` method to be able to pass a modified `dict` to the serializer. You can just copy [the original definition](https://www.cdrf.co/3.12/rest_framework.mixins/CreateModelMixin.html#create)

Afterwards you can add the user to the request data by making a copy, modifying it, and passing it to the serializer:

```py
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    user_id = self.request.user.id
    domain = request.data['domain']
    new_data = request.data.copy()
    new_data.update({"user": user_id})
        
    can_create_task = self.task_service.can_create_task(user=request.user, domain_name=domain)

    if not can_create_task:
            raise PermissionDenied(code=None, detail=None)

    # original definition of create() with new_data
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=new_data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_create(serializer)
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Comment: I get the following error on the line that updates the request data:
`AttributeError: This QueryDict instance is immutable`

Comment: Since `request.data` is immutable, I edited my original answer to address this issue, let me know if it works please

Answer (score 0):

The correct method of doing this, [according to Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/#associating-snippets-with-users), is to override the `perform_create()` method in your ViewSet, which is responsible of creating an instance of a model using a serializer. You can pass additional data to the serializer:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

The original definition of the `perform_create()` method can be found [here](https://www.cdrf.co/3.12/rest_framework.generics/CreateAPIView.html#perform_create).

Comment: This doesn't work because `serializer.is_valid()` is called before `self.perform_create()` in the `CreateModelMixIn`.

Comment: The accepted answer in this post might work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37613293/django-rest-framwork-get-user-in-serializer

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to your problem would be using the "extra_kwargs" field inside your Meta class,for your case it would be something like this:

```
class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ['id', 'created', 'domain']
        extra_kwargs = {'user': {'default': serializers.CurrentUserDefault()}}
```